# How to display two-words author in @article entry in bibtex?

Tags: bibliographies, bibtex, overleaf, apacite

I would like to use bibtex bibliography in apacite style. The bibtex entry I am using is the following:

```
@article{atlas2008,
  title={The ATLAS experiment at the CERN large hadron collider},
  author={ATLAS Collaboration},
  journal={Journal of instrumentation},
  volume={3},
  pages={S08003},
  year={2008}
}
```

The problem is that I can't display both works of the author field in the text when using `\cite`. I've tried many different combinations for the author field (`{ATLAS~Collaboration}`, `{ATLAS, Collaboration}`, `"{ATLAS Collaboration}"`...) but I always get something like `(Collaboration, 2008)` instead of `(ATLAS Collaboration, 2008)`.

You can find a sample overleaf project [here](https://www.overleaf.com/read/wmftnrcrnkgk) that better explains my use case.

How can I display both words as the author's name in the text?

Comment: Adding another pair of curled brackets around your author should be sufficient (`{{ATLAS Collaboration}}` instead of `{ATLAS Collaboration}`).

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE.

Comment: Thanks a lot @Lukas, I can confirm that works!

Comment: Also, thanks @Mico for the warm welcome :))